# JDBC code is giving IllegalAccessError for MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database-metadata, illegalaccessexception

I am getting the following error while retrieving the database tables primary keys, foreign keys and the columns information. Basically I am aware that IllegalAccess is related to the accessing private methods etc. May be it is due to incompatible changes.

I am using mysql the following version. And I have only one mysql jar in the classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the stacktrace.

```
IllegalAccessError: com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData$7

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData$7
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.mycompany.filters.ErrorInterceptorFilter.doFilter(ErrorInterceptorFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.mycompany.security.filters.EFWFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:164)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.mycompany.service.impl.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:208)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData$7
    at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys(DatabaseMetaData.java:3747)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.PrimaryKeyDetails.getPrimaryKeys(PrimaryKeyDetails.java:32)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.MetadataProducer.getPrimaryKeys(MetadataProducer.java:345)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.MetadataProducer.setPrimaryKey(MetadataProducer.java:275)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.MetadataProducer.getListOfTables(MetadataProducer.java:241)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.MetadataProducer.getTables(MetadataProducer.java:210)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.MetadataProducer.getDatabase(MetadataProducer.java:88)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.MetadataProducer.getMetadata(MetadataProducer.java:61)
    at com.mycompany.components.metadata.genericdbmetadata.GenericDatabaseMetadataProvider.getMetadata(GenericDatabaseMetadataProvider.java:120)
    at com.mycompany.components.DatabaseMetadataProvider.executeComponent(DatabaseMetadataProvider.java:34)
    at com.mycompany.services.GenericService.executeService(GenericService.java:92)
    at com.mycompany.services.GenericService.executeService(GenericService.java:39)
    at com.mycompany.services.MetadataProvider.doService(MetadataProvider.java:43)
    at com.mycompany.controller.EfwServicesController.service(EfwServicesController.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor415.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    ... 61 more
```

But frequently I am facing this issue. In my development machine the code works fine but when I deploy to the staging server, I frequently face this issue - but not all the time(Only during some deployments). How to fix the issue?

Additional Info: The Servlet Container being used is Tomcat 6.0.26. And the application is a Spring application.

Server's shared directory jars:

[image]

Comment: How are you building your project (e.g. Maven, Ant, Gradle)?  Which IDE are you using?  Did check the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your WAR to see which version is there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using IntellJ Idea. And I use Maven. Before every deployment I use mvn clean from IDE and then build the war file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The Mysql jar version is same in lib directory

Comment: Any chance there are some stray jars in Tomcats shared directory?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Added the picture that has server's shared lib folder jar files. MySql is put in the application WEBINF using maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've reasoned, the cause is most likely a clash between a compile-time class and a runtime class, where a class has (from JavaDoc) *...irrevocably changed*.

Looking at your shared folder, I'd say that maybe the `mariadb-java-client-1.1.2.jar` is the culprit.

Comment: But can you please explain why it is so? Maria and Mysql are different jars right? I dont have control on the server.

Comment: Maria is a fork of mysql, and I'm pitching the possibility that it might hijack some of your supplied Mysql classes, since it's first on the classpath. In any case, it's never a good idea to put JDBC jars in shared!

Comment: Yeah. I too don't prefer putting in shared folder. But unfortunately I don't have control. Thank you.

Comment: Can you guide me how programatically we can avoid loading a specific jar using class loaders? I mean getting connection only from that jar instead of others.